# A man wants to send me money? Not sure if it’s a scam

Tags: united-states

A man claims he wants to send me money to my credit card. He wants me to send him a picture of both the front and back side. He claims that he’s going to send it to his accountant and put me on a payroll. He also wants my login information. I’m not sure what to do , it’s not like I have a balance on it or he can take any money out of my savings, but with the picture it gives him all of the information to use it online.

Comment: I have never even done this or have been in this situations so I just don’t know

Comment: Online username and password he said

Comment: Of course it is a scam.

Comment: Just think for a moment: why should he need your login information? Especially your password? Why should he need a picture of your CC, especially with the CVC on the back side? You know that you are not supposed to tell the password to anyone, so why should you do that? I cannot understand how people keep falling to this kind of pattern.

Comment: If you send these photos AND the login information, you would find yourself with dozens of maxed out credit cards.  They would mine your account for personal information (secret questions, address, phone number).  They would change your password so you can't get back in.  They would change your recovery methods so you can't recover your account.  They would try your password, or variations of it at multiple credit card sites.  They would open new accounts with as many CCC's as they could until stopped.  Every account would be maxed out.  If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is.

Answer (score 8):

You can't add someone to payroll via credit card. If they want to add you to payroll they'd have you fill out an I-9 and likely a W-4, proper tax forms, but you shouldn't provide such information if you aren't actually accepting a proper job and have taken steps to verify the employer isn't a scammer in cases of online job opportunities.

If this person really wants to send you money suggest they use Venmo/Zelle or some other legitimate money transfer solution that doesn't require compromising security.

If they are unwilling to use a legitimate method, it's because they weren't interested in sending you money in the first place, only in scamming you.